# How to create e2e Tests depends on server date time?

Tags: spring-boot

I have an Angular Frontend and a Spring Boot Backend.

Some Endpoints are heavy depend on backends server datetime.

Here is some prototype example for the Backend to understand my problem.

```
@Get
Response cancelOrder(int id){
 if( datetime > 2pm && datetime <3pm)
    return "Canceled"
 else
  Bad Request
```

I want to write a complete e2e Test with Playwright.

```
  shouldCancelOrder
  shouldNotCancelOrder
```

How I can write an e2e Test to test appications behavior at different clock time? Its also very important that no test specific code will land on production.

I think this is a Spring Boot question, if not pls correct me.

Comment: I think it is important for you that you inject objects that provide you with system date and time. Then you can add a configuration for your e2e tests that have special implementations that you can configure so your e2e tests will get exactly the time you need. It is important that you don't work with a real system time for your tests or their results will not be reliably reproduceable.

Comment: Exactly, how I cann tell my Backend to use a specific server date time from outside?

Comment: How do you start your backend for the e2e tests? If you want to automate the e2e tests, you have to find a mechanism that also starts the backend and specifies a Spring profile for that.